# Can Ubuntu 22.04 make a virtual drive for a folder?

Tags: mount, 22.04, directory, cd-drive

I have a SSD mounted in **/ArchJared** and can access it and subfolders just fine from my Ubunto 22.04 command line.

I have an install program which wants me to place a CD in a drive so it can copy some files.  I'm running the installer under Wine as the program is a Windows executable.

I don't have a CD drive on my Ubuntu machine.  On a Windows machine, I have copied all the files from a installation CD to a folder on my SSD **/ArchJared/MS-Apps/Office2K**, and then carried it to the Ubuntu machine and mounted it as **/ArchJared**, NTFS file system.

Now I need a virtual CD for the install program to access (Yes, it insists on A CD), which it will find by accessing each CD drive on the system.  It is not prompting for a file or directory.  The whole prompt is *Please insert volume 'OFFICE11' (needed for package 'office2003pro')*

How can I setup Ubuntu to have a virtual CD containing the files from **/ArchJare/MS-Apps/Office2K**?

Comment: If there is a "hidden" copy protection on the CD this will never work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup a cdrom drive in Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55275/how-to-setup-a-cdrom-drive-in-wine)